# Achieving name encapsulation while using 'define' over 'let'

Tags: scheme

In an attempt to emulate simple OOP in scheme (just for fun), I have caught myself repeating the following pattern over and over:

```
(define my-class    ; constructor
  (let ((let-for-name-encapsulation 'anything))
    ; object created from data is message passing interface
    (define (this data)
      (lambda (m)
         (cond ((eq? m 'method1) (method1 data))
               ((eq? m 'method2) (method2 data))
               (else (error "my-class: unknown operation error" m)))))
    ;
    (define (method1 data)
      (lambda (arg1 ...)
         ... ))  ; code using internal 'data' of object
    ;
    (define (method2 data)
      (lambda (arg2 ...)
         ... ))
    ;
    ; returning three arguments constructor (say)
    ;
    (lambda (x y z) (this (list 'data x y z)))))
```

I decided to wrap everything inside a `let ((let-for-name-encapsulation ...` so as to avoid leaking names within the global environment while still
being able to use the `define` construct for each internal function name, which enhances readability. I prefer this solution to the unsightly construct `(let ((method1 (lambda (...` but I am still not very happy because of the somewhat artificial `let-for-name-encapsulation`. Can anyone suggests something simple which would make the code look even nicer?. Do I need to learn macros to go beyond this?

Comment: Yes, macros will do the job just fine here.

Comment: An empty `let` should do the same thing, right? `(define my-class (let () (define ...) ...))`?

Comment: @leppie thank you, I will get on that.

Comment: @AlexKnauth yes you are right, and it is actually better I think. I will do that from now on, until I know about macros, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use that pattern often, but you don't actually need to define any variables:

```
(define binding
  (let ()
    (define local-binding1 expression)
    ...
    procedure-expression)))
```

I've seen it in reference implementations of SRFIs so it's a common pattern. Basically it's a way to make `letrec` without the extra identation and lambdas. It can easily be made a macro to make it even flatter:

```
(define-syntax define/lexical
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ binding body ...)
     (define binding
       (let ()
         body ...)))))

;; test
(define/lexical my-class

  (define (this data)
    (lambda (m)
      (cond ((eq? m 'method1) (method1 data))
            ((eq? m 'method2) (method2 data))
            (else (error "my-class: unknown operation error" m)))))

  (define (method1 data)
    (lambda (arg1 ...)
      ... ))  ; code using internal 'data' of object

  (define (method2 data)
    (lambda (arg2 ...)
      ... ))
  ;; returning three arguments constructor (say)
  (lambda (x y z) (this (list 'data x y z))))

;; it works for procedures that return procedures as well
(define/lexical (count start end step)
  (define ...)
  (lambda ...))
```

Of course you could use macros to simplify your object system as well.